# Prove that $\mathbb{P} \left(\{ \| S_n \|<\varepsilon \; \; \text{for infinitely many n} \} \right)$ is 0 or 1

Tags: probability

How to prove that for $X_1, X_2, \ldots  : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ being i.i.d. random variables, $\varepsilon >0$ and $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n X_i$

BEFORE EDIT(wrong problem, but I'd rather let it be here):

$\{ \| S_n \|<\varepsilon \; \; \text{for infinitely many n}  \}$  is a tail event, which means that $\mathbb{P} \left(\{ \| S_n \|<\varepsilon \; \; \text{for infinitely many n}  \} \right) $ is either $0$ or $1$ ?

AFTER EDIT: After Did's comment I change question to show that

$\mathbb{P} \left(\{ \| S_n \|<\varepsilon \; \; \text{for infinitely many n}  \} \right) $ is either $0$ or $1$

although it's not a tail event.

Comment: This is **not** a tail event (but other arguments show that indeed its probability is 0 or 1).

Comment: I made some changes. Thank you for your useful comment!